# Cakephp 3 not working properly on ngnix

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, cakephp-3.0

I am quite new on `nginx` server. Recently I have change my server from `apache` to `nginx` and move the code into a subfolder for testing purpose. Now I am facing issue of `404 not found` for sub pages, css, js and images. Code is in `cakephp V3`.

Here is my nginx config

```
# You may add here your
 server {
location /myproj{
 alias /usr/share/nginx/html/public_html/myproj/webroot;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # prevent recursion
    if ($request_uri ~ /webroot/index.php) {
        break;
    }

    rewrite ^/myproj$ /myproj/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/myproj/webroot/(.*) /myproj/webroot/index.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/myproj/(.*)$ /myproj/webroot/$1 last;
}
 }
```

and `cakephp` config is

```
 'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
        'base' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        'webroot' => 'webroot',
        'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
        'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
        'base' => '/myproj',
        'fullBaseUrl' => false,
        'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
        'paths' => [
            'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
            'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
            'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
        ],
    ],
```

Edit : I managed to run that, I move `location /myproj{` under already created `server {` settings and comment the one I have created. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in to the config file

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```